# How do you extract tuple elements and do some operations on them?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, tuples

**Input:**

```
lits_tuple = [
("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4",    2),
("x1", "x4",    80),
("x4", "z1",    24)]
```

the last element will always be a numeric, float or integer

**Expected Result:**

**{"x1": 82}** # Because we had **x1** in the first tuple with value **2**, and **x1** in tuple2 with value **80**; 2+80 = 82

**{"x2": 2}** # Because we had **x2** only in the first tuple with value **2**

**{"x3": 2}** # Because we had **x3** only in the first tuple with value **2**

**{"x4": 106}** # Because we had **x4** in the first tuple with value **2**, and **x4** in tuple2 with value **80** and **x4** in tuple3 with value **24**; 2+80+24 = 106

**{"z1": 24}** # Because we had **z1** only in the last tuple with value **24**

I started extracting the tuple manually to see if I can generalize, but then got tired and fell asleep.

```
tuple1 = lits_tuple[0]
last_element_tuple1 = tuple1[-1]
range_other_element_tuple1 = [i for i in range(len(lits_tuple[0])-1) ]
len_other_element_tuple1 = len(lits_tuple[0])-1
```

```
last_element_tuplek = lits_tuple[k-1][-1]
range_other_element_tuplek = [i for i in range(len(lits_tuple[k-1])-1) ]
len_other_element_tuplek = len(lits_tuple[k-1])-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may iterate on each `keys,nb` rows, with the pack syntax `*keys` so all first elements are collected in `keys` and the last one in `nb`

Then use a `defaultdict` to increment each one's value

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = [
    ("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", 2),
    ("x1", "x4", 80),
    ("x4", "z1", 24)
]

results = defaultdict(int)

for *keys, nb in values:
    for key in keys:
        results[key] += nb

print(results)
# {'x1': 82, 'x2': 2, 'x3': 2, 'x4': 106, 'z1': 24}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for the trick. I spent more than two days on it thinking to come up with a solution myself. :)